# What's the name of this unknown succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

I bought this rare succulent from Metrotown, the girl she said she does not know this succulent's name, so can anybody give this plant's name and basic care guide?
[image: unknown succulent down view]

[image: unknown succulent side view]

Answer (score 4):

My guess is Echeveria 'Lola' or Elegans.  Mexican Snowball is the common name of the latter. It is definitely an Echeveria...so many different varieties.  Does this picture look similar?

You need to get a tiny clay pot with a hole at the bottom. More light less water! A tiny bit of balanced fertilizer. Use only potting soil, potting soil made for cactus. No rock or gravel at the bottom of the pot. Water only when the pot, soil and plant feel very light. The pot should be 3" diameter 2" or less in height unless you combine this guy with other succulents.
[Echeveria 'Lola'](http://welchwrite.com/agn/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/echeveria-lola.jpg)

Comment: You need to get a tiny clay pot with a hole at the bottom.  More light less water!  A tiny bit of balanced fertilizer.  Use only potting soil, potting soil made for cactus.  No rock or gravel at the bottom of the pot. Water only when the pot, soil and plant feel very light.  The pot should be 3" diameter 2" or less in height unless you combine this guy with other succulents.

Comment: plus 1 for Echeveria - not sure its that particular variety though, but Echeveria it is. Also, plus 1 for the advice in your comment, but as its so important, I think you should make it part of the answer, Stormy! Doesn't have to be a clay pot though, plastic will do, anything's  better than what its in currently, it won't survive long in its current growing conditions...